# H2o flow, is it possible to explain individual predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

I'm a new user of H2o flow. Not much of a coder so I like the point and click interface. I was wondering if after building a model, and using it to score a data set, there is any way to generate output that would tell me for each record, the reasons the score is what it is.

As an example, I've created a model that predicts the risk of hospital re-admissions using the autoML feature within flow.

It actually works really well, but when I use it, I'll be sending highly ranked patients to clinical people, and they want to know "why was this person highly ranked".

Is there any way to show what variables in the model led to the prediction for each person as an output that I could export into a database to use in a reporting tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is related to Machine Learning Interpretability techniques. In H2O-3 the two available are: the [variable importance plot](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#interpreting-model-results) (which tells you which features have the greatest impact on the models decisions) and [Partial Dependence Plots](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#partial-dependence-plots) which give you a sense of how an individual features (aka columns or variables) impact the model's average prediction.

For an overview of available machine learning interpretability techniques I'd recommend taking a look at H2O.ai's [MLI booklet](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/booklets/MLIBooklet.pdf) (though please note that these techniques are, for the most part, only provided in a different product - so if you wanted to use them you would have to code the techniques yourself).